# 22J 6KV and 33J 6KV are two kinds of ceramic cap that seems to be burned out. What do I replace it with?

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, damage, ceramic

These capacitors are located in `power supply module DPS-279BPA` section where it is marked with high voltage area. It is a Phillips LCD television`Phillips 37PFL5603D/10` with no picture and audio, Though it shows the power light in front panel. After I opened the back lid and noticed that these 3 capacitors turned black. Not sure if damaged or not. Other similar cap are still blue in original color. Not having multimeter and ESR I am not able to test these these out. 
I guess replacement parts will cost less than the multimeter or other measuring devices so thing to just find the replacement part and replace and see if really needed go for other options. 
I hope I am not in a wrong place, I am sorry that I could not be detailed than this!

[image][image] I tried to search the actual part specifications as suggested but was unable to find appropriate no. I have uploaded the some more pictures hope helps. The Manual suggested looks similar.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, some advice: It's very tricky troubleshooting anything without even an inexpensive digital multimeter. Even a low-grade one will allow you to effectively troubleshoot. Honestly, there's no guarantee that these caps are the only ones damaged.

A quick search showed me that this particular power supply (based on the label) is Philips part number 2722 171 00584, a.k.a power supply module DPS-279BPA. If you search online, you may be able to find a complete replacement.

Please add the model number to the question. The best way to find out exactly what these are is by a schematic or bill of material, which should be in the service manual for the set.

(That being said, I believe the parts are non-safety high voltage ceramic disc capacitors, which any major electronics distributor should sell. You could try Digi-Key.)

Update: I found a [service manual](http://www.4shared.com/office/b5q1OhN1/TV_philips_LCD_chassis_Q5222E_.html) which mentions the power supply in your photo. Connectors CN2 and CN3 bring high voltage from the transformer to the backlights, and the four capacitors appear to bring the HV signal down to several protection circuits including overvoltage protection. You should check the integrity of the backlights before trying to fix these caps, it's possible that one of the lamps is dead which led to all of this damage.

Comment: +1, excellent detective work. Really helpful answer given the type of question. Strongly agree on at least getting the inexpensive multimeter first!

Comment: @madmanguruman Thanks, for the awesome support as well as up votes though still not enough to up vote the answer, I know I can take it as answer. I would like to know how would I check if the back lights are working and integrable, I am going to buy the multimeter soon. Wanted to know before hand what I may need more.

Comment: Physical inspection is a start. A bad backlight may show physical evidence of failure (discoloration, etc.) - otherwise you may want to see about simply replacing them (depending on the age of the set - if this TV is 5+ years old, I'd consider replacing them while its all apart.) It would also be handy to make sure your multimeter can measure capacitance (some don't).

Answer (score 2):

These are 22pF and 33pF "ballast capacitors" for the backlight CCFL tube driver.  I think Mouser sells those.

In LCD displays, the backlight driver can be a fire hazard, so the display controller will always shut down the entire display when it detects excess current (or low current) on those drivers.   Swapping in all new high-volt caps is a cheap first test, and might fix the problem.

I've found that most of the failed LCD displays in our department are caused by the CCFL backlight drivers.

Also look carefully at all the main electrolytic capacitor cans on that entire board.  Check for swollen tops, discolored PCBs, etc.   Often a dead 1000uF capacitor will lead to many other problems, including overvoltage on the CCFL drivers.